# How to handle missing values in a Random Forest model?

Tags: r, random-forest, missing-data

I have a data with a binary target variable and some predictors. I tried running a random forest model and failed. First of all, I found it hard to enter all predictors to the model. I did:
randomForest(Target ~ P1 + P2 + P3, data = dataset), however, I have more than 3 predictors, and I do not know how to declare them all together. Can I say to R to take P1 to P30 ? Secondly, the model did not run. After some research I realized, that random forest cannot handle missing values. I wanted to ask you, how can I set a random forest if I have missing values in my data ? Can you please guide me, or give me a package that will actually work? (I tried the randomforest package). Thank you !

Comment: Questions that are primarily about programming within specific statistical packages are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site and may be closed.  If you have a statistical question, please edit your post to emphasize it.  Otherwise, take a look at the collection of [links to internet support for statistical packages](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software) that we maintain on this site.

Comment: Decision trees are very good at handling missing data -- it is unclear what do you mean..? If you ask simply about "what package to use", than, as already noted, this is off-topic.

Comment: I would ask "what package are you using" and then I would suggest that one approach is "missing variable imputation" - for which libraries exist.  You could also use the "complete.cases" command in R to only feed in non-missing values.